# Using :lgrep command in Vim and hiding results

Tags: vim

I love using the `:lgrep` command in Vim to create a location list for the current buffer. For example I can use it with a Perl regex by doing:

`:lgrep -P 'pattern' %`

However, I don't like the fact that the results of the grep are displayed, obscuring my Vim session, after the grep completes. I want the results to be placed into the location list window, but for the output of the grep (to the screen) to be suppressed. Normally, after the grep is complete, Vim hides all windows and displays the results of the grep in my terminal. Then I have to `Press ENTER or type command to continue` to get back to the Vim session.

This is annoying.

I usually immediately open a location list window and navigate the results using that window. I want to suppress the displaying of the grep results and then prompting me to hit ENTER to continue.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, just prepend `:silent` to the command:

```
:silent lgrep -P 'pattern' %
```

Excerpt from `:help :silent`:

> ```
>   ":silent" will also avoid the hit-enter prompt.  When
>   using this for an external command, this may cause the
>   screen to be messed up.  Use |CTRL-L| to clean it up
>   then.
> ```

Comment: This is great, except for being forced to use Ctrl-l to do cleanup afterwards. Is there any way for it to auto-repaint or something.

Comment: You could try `:exe 'silent lgrep -P 'pattern' %' | redraw!`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `:lvim` instead of `:lgrep`.

Because it uses an internal routine it doesn't suspend Vim and doesn't force you to hit `<CR>` or `:redraw` anything:

```
:lvim pattern % | lw
```

And for a really low-tech approach:

```
:il[ist] pattern
:n <------------------- your chosen line number
```